# Using ng-options with a JSON object not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to take an object and have a `<select>` that uses the key, value pairs to assign the value and label of the `<option>`s.  For some reason it is not showing up correctly.

I have this JSON object:

```
$scope.ServerData = {
            'HostedExchange': {
                'Exchange EWS (Exchange2007+)': 'EWS',
                'Exchange WebDAV (Exchange2003)': 'Webdav',
                'IMAP': 'Imap',
                'POP': 'Pop',
                'ActiveSync': 'ActiveSync'
            },
            'OnPremiseExchange': {
                'Exchange EWS (Exchange2007+)': 'EWS',
                'Exchange WebDAV (Exchange2003)': 'Webdav',
                'IMAP': 'Imap',
                'POP': 'Pop',
                'ActiveSync': 'ActiveSync'
            },
            'Google': {
                'IMAP': 'Imap'
            },
            'HostedMail': {
                'Exchange EWS (Exchange2007+)': 'EWS',
                'Exchange WebDAV (Exchange2003)': 'Webdav',
                'IMAP': 'Imap',
                'POP': 'Pop',
                'ActiveSync': 'ActiveSync'
            },
            'LotusNotes': {
                'IMAP': 'Imap',
                'POP': 'Pop',
                'Notes Traveler (ActiveSync)': 'ActiveSync'
            },
            'ConnectWise': {
                'IMAP': 'Imap',
                'POP': 'Pop'
            },
            'CommuniGate': {
                'IMAP': 'Imap',
                'POP': 'Pop',
                'AirSync': 'ActiveSync'
            },
            'Zimbra': {
                'IMAP': 'Imap',
                'POP': 'Pop',
                'ActiveSync': 'ActiveSync'
            },
            'Other': {
                'Exchange EWS (Exchange2007+)': 'EWS',
                'Exchange WebDAV (Exchange2003)': 'Webdav',
                'IMAP': 'Imap',
                'POP': 'Pop',
                'ActiveSync': 'ActiveSync'
            }
        }
```

Where we use another `<select>` to select the `key` of this object to then look up the object used the for second `<select>`.  That part is working just fine. Here is the HTML

```
<li>
                     <label>Email system</label>
                     <select name="EmailSystemType" ng-model="model.EmailSystemType">
                         <option value="">select a system</option>
                         <option value="HostedExchange">Hosted Exchange</option>
                         <option value="OnPremiseExchange">On Premise Exchange</option>
                         <option value="Google">Google</option>
                         <option value="HostedMail">Hosted Mail (e.g. Go Daddy)</option>
                         <option value="LotusNotes">Lotus Notes</option>
                         <option value="ConnectWise">ConnectWise</option>
                         <option value="CommuniGate">CommuniGate</option>
                         <option value="Zimbra">Zimbra</option>
                         <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>


                 </li>
                 <li>
                     <label>Protocol</label>
                     <select name="Protocol" ng-model="model.EmailSystemProtocol" ng-options="v as k for (k, v) in ServerData[model.EmailSystemType]">
                         <option value="">select a system above</option>
                     </select>

                 </li>
```

The problem is the DOM shows the `<option>` value as being the same as the label, which is the `key` of these objects.  Instead, I want the `key` to be the option value and the `value` to be the option label.

**UPDATE**

Actually I just realized that Angular doesn't use the value with ng-model.  My model on the `$scope` is showing the correct value, but the DOM doesn't show what I thought it would show.  The page should actually be working fine then, just strange that Angular doesn't show this in the DOM

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/gLETB1HHMry4lKrWmFjQ?p=preview is that what you need ?

Answer (score 0):

This will do

script

```
  $scope.titleize = function(txt) {
    return txt.replace(/[a-z][A-Z]/g, function(s) {return s[0]+' '+s[1]});
  };
```

html

```
<select ng-model="foo" 
  ng-options="key as titleize(key) for (key , value) in ServerData">
  <option value="">select a system</option>
</select>
```